# Firebase: Unable to add new app (error message: Request contains an invalid argument)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I'm trying to create a Web App in Firebase so I can obtain credenials, but it is refusing to do so. I am not able to find anything on this error message.

I'm getting the error state "An unexpected error has occurred. [Reason: Request contains an invalid argument.]" [Error message in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMziM.png)

---

Also when I try to create it through the CLI it refuses

```
firebase apps:create WEB "Web app"
```

Results in:

```
[debug] [2020-10-29T13:04:48.471Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Thu, 29 Oct 2020 13:04:48 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[debug] [2020-10-29T13:04:48.472Z] <eye3 title='/ExecuteService.SingleExecute, INVALID_ARGUMENT'/> APPLICATION_ERROR;execute_service/ExecuteService.SingleExecute;Not a valid controlling product: FIREBASE. Property id:<188538656>
com.google.apps.framework.request.StatusException: <eye3 title='INVALID_ARGUMENT'/> generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Not a valid controlling product: FIREBASE. Property id:<188538656>;AppErrorCode=3;StartTimeMs=1603976687479;tcp;Deadline(sec)=30.0;ResFormat=UNCOMPRESSED;Originator=mobilesdk-devrel-frontend;Tag=IncomingMethod/FiredataInternalService.ProcessQueueMessage;ServerTimeSec=0.247247872;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EndUserCredsRequested;EffSecLevel=privacy_and_integrity;ReqFormat=UNCOMPRESSED;ReqID=ae3e58762b9b13f4;GlobalID=6831ddc8c7f8475;Server=[2002:a81:9b16:0:b029:19c:c7d4:d379]:4001
[debug] [2020-10-29T13:04:48.476Z] FirebaseError: <eye3 title='/ExecuteService.SingleExecute, INVALID_ARGUMENT'/> APPLICATION_ERROR;execute_service/ExecuteService.SingleExecute;Not a valid controlling product: FIREBASE. Property id:<188538656>
com.google.apps.framework.request.StatusException: <eye3 title='INVALID_ARGUMENT'/> generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Not a valid controlling product: FIREBASE. Property id:<188538656>;AppErrorCode=3;StartTimeMs=1603976687479;tcp;Deadline(sec)=30.0;ResFormat=UNCOMPRESSED;Originator=mobilesdk-devrel-frontend;Tag=IncomingMethod/FiredataInternalService.ProcessQueueMessage;ServerTimeSec=0.247247872;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EndUserCredsRequested;EffSecLevel=privacy_and_integrity;ReqFormat=UNCOMPRESSED;ReqID=ae3e58762b9b13f4;GlobalID=6831ddc8c7f8475;Server=[2002:a81:9b16:0:b029:19c:c7d4:d379]:4001
    at OperationPoller.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/operation-poller.js:33:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/operation-poller.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
[error]
```

Does anyone has experience with this error and knows how to deal with it? Firebase is enabled (and working already).

Comment: If you're having problems with the Firebase console, or the Firebase CLI isn't giving you a helpful error message, contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I have the same problem right now.

Comment: Same issue here. I have reported it to Firebase support - hopefully they will pick it up quickly.

Comment: Hello , I am also getting the same problem. Does anyone have any solution? Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681945/is-that-possible-to-add-android-app-to-firebase-project-programmatically-using-f

Comment: I am also facing same problem

Comment: I am using from try api window

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and logged a support ticket.  I heard back this morning that it was a bug which has now been resolved.  It is now working again for me.