# Is that possible to add android app to firebase project programmatically using firbase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there any method to add a android app to exiting firebase project programmatically and i need the google-services.json as result then i need to add sha key with that same app using node-js
online documentation not solve my problem or i don't understand how to do it from that documentation

Thankyou for your answer i flowed it and facing another issue
@admin and @Frank van Puffelen please check
when i try to create android it showing this error.

```
{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }
```

I send post request from live api test window
and in parent i set it as `projects/343202254462`

```
{ "displayName": "testing", "name": "te4sting", "packageName": "io.asdasd.fdsfdsf", "projectId": "324324324", "appId": "wdeqwe" }
```

Comment: I updated question please check

Answer (score 2):

There is a [REST api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest), Firebase Management API, which lets you control the apps connected and other such admin work. Friendly note, make sure you restrict all client api keys from using this api!

> REST Resource: v1beta1.projects.androidApps
>
> create POST /v1beta1/{parent=projects/*}/androidApps

Comment: Good find Amin! That's indeed the way to do this. 

Comment: when i try to create android it showing this error.    {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}                    <br>{
  "displayName": "testing",
  "name": "te4sting",
  "packageName": "io.asdasd.fdsfdsf",
  "projectId": "324324324",
  "appId": "wdeqwe"
}.  @FrankvanPuffelen please check this